# IBM DB2 10.5 FP3 -sql1042c an unexpected system error occurred. sqlstate=58004 db2 connect windows

Tags: db2

We recently upgraded some of our employee's DB2 Runtime client from 9.7 (32 bit) to 10.5 FP3 (64 bit) in their windows 7 machines.After that some of them are having issues when trying to connect to our database through an excel macro or even through db2 clp.They are getting the below error

***IBM CLI Driver SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred. 
SQLSTATE=58004***

I have checked their db2diag.log and i see this

```
2015-06-17-17.06.34.820000-240    I11076H445            LEVEL: Error
PID     : 1216                 TID : 5372           PROC : EXCEL.EXE
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: MLIW*****
EDUID   : 5372

FUNCTION: DB2 Common, Cryptography, cryptDynamicLoadGSKitCrypto, probe:998

MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000007=-1879048185=ECF_UNKNOWN
          Unknown

DATA #1 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes

60

DATA #2 : String, 11 bytes

gsk8sys.dll*
```

*Please advise.*

Comment: `gsk8sys.dll` is a 32-bit library. The fact that DB2 attempts to load it means that a 32-bit application wants to connect to the database. To make this work you will need to install a 32-bit DB2 client.

Comment: Thanks.But if other user logs into the same machine and try,it works.It is just that it does not work for this user.I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

The symptom may be depended on the installation order of Db2 connect and a program (EXCEL).  If DB2 connect is installed first, it should not be occurred.

So it is nice that checking installation order for EXCEL and Db2 at both OK and NG user's machines.  If don't remember, try to remove and re-install both products once then install Db2 connect first.

Hope this helps.